# CommonJS to ES6 migration exports. to export

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm migrating a Nativescript project from version 6.8 to 8.1.  This involves converting modules from CommonJS to ES6, which is mostly just converting function exports, so that

```
exports.foo = function(args) { ... }
```

becomes

```
export function foo(args) { ... }
```

and if you invoke the function from within the module, `exports.foo()` becomes just `foo()`.

In addition to my own code I'm finding I'm having to migrate some of the plugins I use as newer versions aren't available.  So far so good, *except* for this block of code:

```
/**
 * List of outout formats.
 */
(function (OutputFormat) {
    /**
     * PNG
     */
    OutputFormat[OutputFormat["PNG"] = 1] = "PNG";
    /**
     * JPEG
     */
    OutputFormat[OutputFormat["JPEG"] = 2] = "JPEG";
})(exports.OutputFormat || (exports.OutputFormat = {}));
var OutputFormat = exports.OutputFormat;
```

I'm having a hard time following what this does, much less converting it to ES6 syntax.  For context, here's the type definition:

```
export declare enum OutputFormat {
    /**
     * PNG
     */
    PNG = 1,
    /**
     * JPEG
     */
    JPEG = 2,
}
```

I'd welcome any suggestions on how to convert this.

Comment: "*`export declare enum OutputFormat`*" - are you actually using typescript? That IIFE looks like it was generated by a transpiler. Try to get the actual source code of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at what it's invoked with:

```
(exports.OutputFormat || (exports.OutputFormat = {}));
```

- If `exports.OutputFormat` is truthy, it'll be the parameter
- Otherwise, the following expression will be the parameter: `exports.OutputFormat = {}`, which will:

  - create an empty object
  - assign that empty object to `exports.OutputFormat`
  - evaluate to that empty object

Unless `OutputFormat` is referenced elsewhere in this module, which seems unlikely, you can turn it into ES6 module syntax with:

```
export const OutputFormat = {
  PNG: 1,
  1: "PNG",
  JPEG: 2,
  2: "JPEG",
};
```

While you can also export an empty object and then run

```
OutputFormat[OutputFormat["PNG"] = 1] = "PNG";
OutputFormat[OutputFormat["JPEG"] = 2] = "JPEG";
```

, those lines of code are much more confusing than they need to be, so I'd refactor them to the above.

(or you could iterate over an array of `[["PNG", 1], ["JPEG", 2]]` and assign)

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, that code is much more confusing than it needs to be, and it's satisfying when such convoluted code can be reduced to something so simple.  I'll mark this was the accepted answer.